# Angular 2: Calling a child component

Tags: angular, ionic2

I've updated my ionic app from beta 11 to rc0. So it means I've switched from angular2 rc4 to angular2 stable.

I am trying to use a custom component that I'm calling from *home-page.html*

```
<slider-component [title]="sliderTitle[0]" [songs]="recentlyViewedSongs" [viewId]="RecentViewId" ></slider-component>
```

In *slider-component.ts*, I have a console.log which remains always undefined

```
export class SliderComponent {

    @Input() title: string = "";
    @Input() songs: any; 
    @Input() viewId: any = []; //stores id of songs to be shown

    constructor(
        public nav: NavController, 
    ) { 
        console.log("In the SliderComponent, this.songs", this.songs);  //shows an empty array
    }
```

In my *app.module.ts*, I'm using *@NgModule* like this

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    SliderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    SliderComponent
  ],
  providers: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement `OnInit` and access your data bound properties (title, songs etc.) in `ngOnInit()` method. As per the life cycle they are not initialized at the time of constructor execution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was able to get the variable with ngOnInit

Answer (score 0):

Did you import your component in the `home-page.ts` ? and included under `@Component` ?

Typically it's something like

```
#home-page.ts
`import {SliderComponent} from '../../components/slider-component/slider-component';`

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home-page/home-page.html',
  directives: [SliderComponent],
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's all working now. I thought _directives_ and _providers_ are no longer needed in _@Component_ as we have ngModule taking care of everything.
I've not used _directives_